# Conditional Rendering in Meteor + React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to get some conditional rendering in Meter + React.  I only want a component to show up if the number of items returned from a collection === 0.

I tried this:

```
renderInputForm () {
if (Tokens.find().count()) return;
return (<TokenForm />);
}
```

and put {this.renderInputForm()} in the main render(), but then it flashes  for a split second before hiding it…

I know why the flash is happening but trying to avoid it ….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wait for the data to finish with synchronization. The flash is there because initially MiniMongo collections are empty. (Also, you might want to avoid `Collection.find()` in your render function.)

Assuming you use Meteor 1.3.x:

```
export const MyComponent = createContainer(() => {
  let subscription = Meteor.subscribe('something');
  if (!subscription.ready()) return {};
  return {
    tokens: Tokens.find().fetch()
  }
}, InternalComponent);
```

And then check for the existence of `props.tokens` in your React component.

```
class InternalComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.tokens || this.props.tokens.length > 0) return;
    return <TokenForm />;
  }
}
```

Find out more about subscriptions here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe

Comment: Are these two snippets in the same file? I have other code in the render() currently, and trying to determine how to use this InternalComponent properly.

Comment: They can be in the same file, yes. `createContainer` does what `getMeteorData` did in Meteor 1.2, if you're familiar with that. Basically, it just adds a few things to InternalComponent to bind it with React. You can still put all the necessary code into InternalComponent.