# meteor-reactjs: in constructor collection is empty

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6, meteor-react

Due to the fact that I am new in meteor/react I can't figure out how to initialize my state variable.

My problem is that I would like to get

1. my mongo collection through the createContainer from react-meteor-data (as described [here](http://guide.meteor.com/react.html)),
2. use the initialized prop to intialize the state variable

But the prop in the constructor is empty. Only when I the "gotClicked" function is called the prop.allLists is filled with the data from mongo.

Does anyone know why? My guess the data is loaded asynchronously, so that the data is not available yet in the constructor.
What would be a better way to get the data?

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import {AllLists} from '../api/alllists.js'
export default class MyList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();

        console.log(props.allLists)
        console.log(this.props.allLists)
        //allLists is empty

        this.state = {
            lists: props.allLists
        }
    }

    gotClicked(){
        console.log(this.props.allLists)
        //allLists is filled
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" onClick={this.gotClicked.bind(this)}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

MyList.propTypes = {
   allLists: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        allLists: AllLists.find({}).fetch()
    };
}, MyList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the data is loaded asynchronously, and it might not be available in the constructor. However, the callback function you pass to `createContainer` is evaluated again when the data is loaded, and it automatically updates the `props` of your component.

To catch this change, implement the `componentWillReceiveProps` function in your React component.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    lists: nextProps.allLists
  });
}
```

Docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I implemented componentWillReceiveProps function.

Now I receive the props with the result of AllLists.find({}).fetch.

But it seems that when the function is called the fetch hasn’t been finished, because the array has different lengths at different calls.

Comment: You can also check the state of the subscription. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585564/conditional-rendering-in-meteor-react/36585830#36585830

Comment: Ok now it's working! Thanks.
Feels inconvenient to use though.