# Meteor.user() receives custom fields later than _id, emails and roles

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I have a custom field that "shows up late" compared to the other fields in Meteor.user(). It's causing me problems handling data initialization. My question is, why does my custom field show up late? Here's the issue.

I have added a custom field to users like this:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('allusers', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  });  

  Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
      return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                               {fields: {'lastViewedScenarios_id': 1 }});
    } else {
      this.ready();
    }
  });
}
```

And on the client, I get at the user data via createContainer, like this:

```
export default AppContainer = createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('userData');

  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
  };
}, App);
```

But when I look at what happens when the page loads, I see this behavior:

on 1st call to componentWillReceiveProps:

```
currentuser:
  _id : "DNFNaecyNWGMe4HrZ"
  emails : Array[1]
  roles : Array[1] /* SOMETIMES present, sometimes not! */
```

still loading the page, subsequent call to componentWillReceiveProps:

```
currentuser:
  _id : "DNFNaecyNWGMe4HrZ"
  emails : Array[1]
  roles : Array[1]
  lastViewedScenarios_id :MongoID.ObjectID /* Never present until 2nd call! */
```

What the? I am using alanning:roles, and maybe that's doing its own custom publish of userData. Whether that's a factor or not, my custom field lastViewedScenarios_id is only showing up after the initial population of currentuser, even though this data is all in the same Mongo collection.

My code needs to take action on initialization of the currentuser data, and this "initializes a bit at a time" behavior is making clean logic impossible here. Why is this happening, and can I do anything about it other than add lots of ugly initialization and testing for the presence of every field?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to wait for the subscription to be ready before you can safely assume that all the data is there. The data is pushed from the server to the client over WebSocket asynchronously.

Comment: See answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36585830/2805154

Comment: My bad for drawing from examples that didn't include loading/ready. It works now. Here's an observation: this.props.loading can be true on entry into componentWillUpdate(), but becomes false by the time render() and componentDidUpdate() are called. And in that situation, componentWillUpdate() does **not** get called again, which I think means that componentWillUpdate() is NOT being called when there has, in fact, been an update to props. Had to add all my inits to componentDidUpdate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to ensure your data will be fully available when your component calls `componentWillReceiveProps` is to only use your component when your `userData` subscription is ready. This can be achieved by changing your `AppContainer`:

```
export default AppContainer = createContainer(() => {
  const subscriptionHandler = Meteor.subscribe('userData');
  return {
    loading: !subscriptionHandler.ready()
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
  };
}, App);
```

Then in your `App` component you can use the `loading` prop to decide to use the component only when `loading` is false.

Something like this (in your App's `render()` method):

```
{
  this.props.loading ? 
    <div>Loading...</div> :
    <CleanLogicComponent user=this.props.currentUser />
}
```

Then, when `CleanLogicComponent`'s `componentWillReceiveProps` gets called, all user data will be available.